# How to copy a google slide?

Tags: copy, google-slides-api, google-slides

How can I copy a protected google slide? Is that possible?
I have tried multiple methods from javascipt to others, but that did not work.

Comment: Are you the owner of the Slides file? Also please provide the code which you have tried.

Comment: No I'm not the owner.
I have tried some bookmark codes but didn't seem to work

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: javascript:
var n = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src*=docs\\.google]')[0],
    k = document.createElement("a");
k.setAttribute("href",n.getAttribute("src"));
k.setAttribute("target","_blank");
k.setAttribute("style","display:block");
k.innerText = "Open Google Slides";
n.parentElement.insertBefore(k,n);

Comment: javascript: 
var atag = "punch-viewer-content",
    btag = "goog-flat-menu-button-caption",
    ctag = "aria-setsize",
    dtag = "aria-posinset",
    msvg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg"),
    node = document.getElementsByClassName(btag)[0],
    view = document.getElementsByClassName(atag)[0],
    size = node.getAttribute(ctag);
for(var i = 0, data = ""; i!=size; view.click())
   i = node.getAttribute(dtag), data += msvg[0].outerHTML;
document.write(data);

Comment: These two, found it somewhere idk where though